# Upload PowerPoint via AFNetworking gets corrupt

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, powerpoint, corrupt

I receive a successfully response when uploading a PowerPoint via the below code.  It does get upload but the file is corrupt.  When opening the corrupt file on the server via PowerPoint I get this message:

"PowerPoint found a problem with content in filename.pptx.  PowerPoint can attempt to repair the presentation."

```
- (void)updateDocument:(NSString *) path parameters:(FileUploadParameters*)para success:(void (^)(void))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    _postData = nil;
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ConfigurationUtil objectForKey:@"baseURL"]]];


    _postData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByStandardizingPath]];

    _postData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByStandardizingPath] options:NSDataReadingMapped error:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:HTTP_METHOD_POST
                                                                         path:[self getQueryString:path parameter:para]
                                                                   parameters:nil
                                                    constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                                                    {
                                                        [formData appendPartWithFileData:_postData
                                                                                    name:[[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]
                                                                                fileName:[[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]                                                                                mimeType:@"application/powerpoint"];


                                                    }];

    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"WRAP access_token=%@",[Tenant loadSharedTenantInstance].authToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {
             if (success)
              success();
         }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error)
         {
             if (failure)
                failure(error);
         }
     ];
    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: how exactly are the files different? Do they have a different size or some bytes are changed? When trying to find a bug, don't look only into code.

Comment: Are your success or failure blocks getting called?  I'm wondering if the data doesn't finish sending because `operation` goes out of scope at the end of the method.  I've always followed the recommended patten of a singleton HTTP client, and adding the operation to its operation queue.

Comment: The files don't look different and they are the same size.  They're just marked as corrupt.  The repair button in PowerPoint fixes the file but I need the file to not be view as corrupt.  With the same code a PDF can be uploaded with no corruption but not Microsoft Documents (i.e. Excel, Word, PowerPoint).  The success block is getting called.  I am getting a success response.

Comment: Could you try to set the `mimeType` explicitly? Maybe simply as `application/octet-stream`. If the `mimeType` is not set correctly, the data could be corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Your AFNetworking code looks fine.  I don't think that's the culprit.

You can use the `cmp` command line tool to compare the two files (the original and the upload) byte-for-byte and see if there's a difference.  I think there won't be.

More likely: it's a misleading error message, and it's actually a permissions issue on the computer with Powerpoint installed, as outlined in [this Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2387587/en-gb).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this and let you know if it works.  The bytes are different but appendPartWithFileData will do that.  However, that should not corrupt anything else.

Comment: @user2969771 Let us know what happens!

Answer (score 0):

The below code corrects the problem.  It appears that appendPartWithFileData was causing the issue.  It changes the filesize and that seemed to register the file as corrupt.

_postData = nil;
    _postData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByStandardizingPath]];

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
NSString *queryString =[self getQueryString:path parameter:nil];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:queryString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:_postData];

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"WRAP access_token=%@",[Tenant loadSharedTenantInstance].authToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         if (success)
          success();
     }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error)
     {
         if (failure)
            failure(error);
     }
 ];
[operation start];
```